# What am I entering wrong in the port?

Tags: terraria

when I try to log in to a terraria sever, the "accept" button doesn't work. I've tried 7777 in the port but nothing happens.

Comment: I think it would help if you provided more details. As it is we don't have enough to go on because we don't know what _exactly_ you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The port is whatever the server has set as its port. You'll need to find out what the server owner has set. The default is 7777, but it can be changed.